# Disconnect network in Android emulator while keeping ADB alive

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have made a mistake somewhere in my code that my Android app crashes when I switch off the network in the emulator while the app's HTTPClient is making some request.

But I cannot debug it, because when I switched off the network, I also lost the ADB connection. Thus I cannot see what exception is causing the crash.

I have tried switching off the network by:

- F8
- Set 'Data' to 'Unregistered' or 'Denied' in DDMS Emulator Control

I can put my Mac offline and ADB will stay up, but unfortunately I cannot reproduce the crash that way.

**Is there a way to turn off network in the emulator, while keeping ADB alive?** I basically need access to the LogCat entries.

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI, I have resolved my crash problem with a global try-catch and printing logs to the view. But I can't keep doing that -- and would appreciate if someone has a solution for the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run logcat from the device instead of from ADB and redirect it to a file for offline reading.

```
adb shell logcat [-v threadtime] > /sdcard/mylogs/logcat.log
```

Instead of

```
adb logcat [-v threadtime]
```

Then you can get the file when you reconnect to the device.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Definitely better than having to dump logs to a view.

Answer (score 1):

On linux this is pretty simple with iptables firewall. I suppose you trying to debug api calls so just block api host:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d api.example.com -j DROP
```

Sure you can do the same thing with Mac or Windows firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the device into airplane mode, that will still allow you to connect over adb but not give the emulator a connection to the internet. You can also turn off data through eclipse via the emulator control section in ddms by putting in unregistered/denied to the data drop down.

Comment: Airplane mode doesn't work either, the emulator will lose the ADB connection, at least in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but someone might use find for this.

My setup

> Eclipse Kepler with emulated android 4.4

If you want to keep your adb alive and network turned off, you can try this.

1. Start emulated device
2. Activate flight/airplane mode
3. Restart Eclipse
4. It should work! Check DDMS perspective for attached devices or use `adb devices` command